# ui-state-active class does not appear for dynamic click handling in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a link like this:

```
<a id="home">HOME</a>
```

and to handle the click on this:

```
$("#home").on("vclick", function(){
    //code
});
```

The problem is when the `click event` is fired on the link the `ui-state-active` class does not appear on the link.

How to correct this?

I am using `jquery-mobile 1.4.1`

As of now I am using some bad hack. Something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="home" value="HOME" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hack made it work:

```
$(document).on("vclick", "#home", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var obj = $(this);
        var url = obj.attr("id");
        obj.addClass("ui-btn-active");
        $.mobile.changePage(url + ".html");
        $(document).on("pagehide", function(){
            obj.removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        });

    }); // vclick for
```

Comment: can you explain what was the problem and how does this solve it?